# Darwin Term (Fine Structure) and the Taylor expansion of the electric potential energy

Tags: notation, perturbation-theory, calculus, hydrogen

I am trying to derive the Taylor expansion for the potential $U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)$. The general expression for the Taylor expansion is: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n.$$

I am trying to derive the same expression as in the Wikipedia article on [Fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure#:%7E:text=This%20yields%20a,can%20be%20estimated%3A), but my derivation is not proper and it's messy, with multiple punctuality mistakes etc. From my understanding the variable is $\delta\vec r$. So we need to take the derivative with respect to it.

\begin{align}
U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)=& U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec r'-\delta \vec r)^0 \\
&+ \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec x'_i-\delta x_i)^1|_{\delta x_i=0}\\
&+\frac 1 2\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec x'_i-\delta x_i)|_{\delta x_i=0}(\delta \vec x'_j-\delta x_j)|_{\delta x_j=0} +\cdots
\end{align}

I have the following questions for what I wrote above:

1. If we want to be precise, shouldn't I write $\frac{\partial}{\partial \delta x_i}$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ ? Because if am writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ than it looks as if I am taking the derivative with respect to $x_i$.
2. In the Wikipedia article, the 2nd term is written as the product of the Nabla operator and the potential, so a gradient. How do I cleanly produce that expression?

Comment: You are quoting the one-dimensional Taylor formula as the general expression. How familiar are you with the [multi-dimensional version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)?

Comment: I am familiar with it and I realize that the 3rd question is not important, since I understood it

Comment: @kricheli ignoring the 3rd question, could you help me with question 1 and 2?

Comment: Why do you have $(\delta x'_i -\delta x_i)$ instead of just  $\delta x_i$? What do the primes mean?

Comment: @mikestone imitating the Taylor expansion with a root and an arbitrary value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

1. Loose the prime $\delta r$ terms and the weird $|_{\delta x_j=0}$, they make no sense. Your formula should read something like
   $$
   U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)= U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec r)^0 \\
   + \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec r_i)^1\\
   +\frac 1 2\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}U(\vec r + \delta \vec r)|_{\delta \vec r=0}(\delta \vec r_i)(\delta \vec r_j) +\cdots
   $$
   In words: To evaluate the function $U$ at a point that is offset from $\vec{r}$ by $\delta \vec{r}$ take $U$ evaluated at $\vec{r}$ (the first term on the RHS) plus the product of first derivatives of $U$ evaluated at $\vec{r}$ and the components $\delta \vec{r}_i$ in the respective directions of the offset/perturbation we want to use (the second term), plus ....
2. To answer your question no. 1: You have stumbled across something which one might call a touchy subject. In physics conventions for partial derivatives are not always clear and it helps to have a little experience to see what's going on.
   If you're doing analysis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you read something like
   $$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)
   $$
   what is actually meant by this? The problem is that $x$ appears in a double role: denoting the derivative with respect to the first coordinate in $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and the evaluation at some particular value $x$ of the coordinate in the argument.
   Now, how would you read
   $$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(-y,x)\,,
   $$
   is the derivative taken with respect to the first or the second argument? I think a mathematician would be likely to read this as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$ (i.e. the derivative wrt. the first argument) evaluated at $(-y,x)$ (which I think is the correct reading), while some people in physics would read this as "take the expression $f(-y,x)$ and derive wrt. $x$ (in which they are using the partial derivative like a total derivative).
   So, to come back to your question (I hope I haven't confused you above :) ), the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is fine, it just says "partial derivative with respect to the $i$-th component of the functions argument that is usually denoted by $x$". There are other notations like $\partial_i$ for that where you don't face the problem of putting an unnecessary name tag on the function argument when writing down the derivative.
3. To answer your no. 2: This one is quite easy, for a vector $\vec{a}$ and a scalar function $f$ we have
   $$
   \vec{a} \cdot \nabla f = \sum_i \vec{a}_i \partial_i f
   $$
   and you see that the first-order term in Wikipedia using the gradient conforms with the one written down here.